# Атрибут fill в SVG. Каково значение по умолчанию? Для чего указывать fill="none"?

Tags: svg

В учебных заданиях можно увидеть использование атрибута "fill" со значением "none". Особенно смущает такое указание для линий!!!

```
<line fill="none" stroke="black" x1="50" y1="50" x2="200" y2="50"/>
```

Зачем вообще указывать fill для линии? Да и для других фигур, если я хочу оставить их прозрачными. Есть ли значение по умолчанию? Наследуются ли fill от предка и как разрешаются конфликты?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> В учебных заданиях можно увидеть использование атрибута "fill" со
> значением "none". Особенно смущает такое указание для линий!!!

Если линия прямая, то применение `fill="none"` или `fill="индекс цвета"` абсолютно никакой роли не играет.  Более того, если вы не укажете цвет `stroke`, то вы ничего не увидите:

- **fill="purple"**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<line x1="10" y1="50" x2="300" y2="300" fill="purple" />
</svg>
```

- Заполнение пурпурным цветом **fill="purple"** для прямой линии
  игнорируется и при **stroke="green" stroke-width="4"** будет показана
  линия зелёного цвета

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<line x1="10" y1="50" x2="300" y2="300" fill="purple" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

### Криволинейный контур

Абсолютно без разницы, - будет замкнут контур или нет, внутренне пространство фигуры, будет окрашено в чёрный цвет, если не указать `fill="none"`
Другими словами,- значение fill по умолчанию имеет чёрный цвет.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<path d="M10,250 A100,100 0 0 1 210,250" />
</svg>
```

- Добавляем stroke

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<path stroke="red" stroke-width="4"  d="M10,250 A100,100 0 0 1 210,250" />
</svg>
```

- Добавляем fill="none", то есть убираем закраску

```html
  <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300"  >  
    <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"  d="M10,250 A100,100 0 0 1 210,250" />
    </svg>
```

### Все примеры выше работают и для текста SVG

- stroke="red" stroke-width="4"

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<text x="50" y="200" font-size="200px"  stroke="red" stroke-width="4" stroke="red">T </text>
</svg>
```

- stroke="red" stroke-width="4"  **fill="none"**

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" >  
<text x="50" y="200" font-size="200px" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" stroke="red">T </text>
</svg>
```

### Вывод

1. fill="none" служит для удаления дефолтной, чёрной закраски внутреннего пространства  у криволинейных фигур
2. Для прямых линий параметр `fill` не играет никакого значения.
   Указание fill="none" не вызывает ошибку, видимо поэтому и встречается в учебных примерах для прямых линий.

Comment: То есть наследования никакого нет в плане свойства fill? Если группе или всему svg будет использовано fill='blue', на каждую отдельную фигуру внутри это никак не распространяется? Начал учебник по SVG animations, вроде начало бодрое, а потом быстро все на библиотеку ушло. Не могу найти путный учебный курс по SVG. Документация есть, но она не покрывает тем вроде лучших практик и так далее. Можете что-то посоветовать? Спасибо!

Comment: @Leonid не всё так просто в вопросе наследования и стилизации в SVG.  Важную роль играет сложная система иерархии внутренних, внешних и стилей представления SVG: (fill="red") Также наивысший приоритет имеют computed style.  Если интересна данная тема задай пожалуйста новый вопрос

Comment: @Leonid про анимацию SVG, вот одна из самых ценных статей (на мой взгляд) [Все об SVG анимации](https://habr.com/ru/post/450924/)

Answer (score 3):

Атрибут [fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill) имеет два значения в зависимости от используемого контекста.

По умолчанию, когда элементы анимации заканчиваются и их эффекты больше не применяются к значению представления для целевых атрибутов. Атрибут `fill` может использоваться для сохранения значения анимации после окончания активной продолжительности элемента анимации.

Для фигур и текста атрибут `fill` является атрибутом представления, определяющим цвет внутренней части данного графического элемента. То, что называется «интерьер», зависит от самой фигуры и значения `fill-rule` атрибут. Как атрибут представления, он также может использоваться как свойство непосредственно в таблице стилей CSS

---

Насчёт стоит ли указывать: не думаю что является ошибкой, хотя по логике работает только когда путь фигуры заканчивается началом ([closePath - `Z`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8)).